# How to use flutter integration testing to complete the Swipe CardField widget

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, integration-testing

I have a Stripe CardField widget in my app. I am using flutter integration tests and would normally use something like find.byType, or find.byKey, etc, etc, but with CardField, none of the find options seems to work to return a finder which I can then use 'enterText' on.

I have already tried the great idea here https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/widget/finders, by running the test with a breakpoint, then tapping the CardField element, and the Terminal shows a list of about 6 different 'byType' options to try. None of them allow the 'enterText' without crashing the test.

I have also deepdived into the CardField widget to try and find a child TextField or TextFormField, but I always seem to land on a 'AndroidViewSurface' which doesn't work for enterText.

To replicate, add a CardField to a view;

```
CardField(
  onCardChanged: (card) {
   setState(() {});
  },
),
```

And then run a test;

```
  final cardfieldSurface = find.byType(AndroidViewSurface).first;
  await tester.enterText(cardfieldSurface, "4242");
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 10));
```

I have now also tried a few other things...

```
await tester.tapAt(const Offset(90, 170));
await tester.pumpAndSettle();
```

This actually successfully gets focus onto the Card Number field if you are very precise about tapping in the CardField widget but not exactly in the Card Number 'TextField'. So I tried the same approach to tap on the numbers on the numberpad but no luck, the 'target' image appears showing taps higher than the keyboard when Y offset is low, but when the Y offset is where the numberpad is, the 'target' image doesn't show, so I assume the taps are happening 'underneath' the numberpad.

I have also tried variations of;

```
tester.sendKeyEvent(LogicalKeyboardKey.numpad2,
  platform: Platform.operatingSystem, character: "2");
```

But no text appears in the Card Number field.

Comment: It is intentionally difficult to interact with Stripe's (assuming you meant Stripe rather than Swipe based on the included tags) frontend UI components in this way. What are you hoping to test in this manner, and is there another way to accomplish that? Typically Stripe recommends mocking the responses that your test flow needs from their service rather than hitting it during testing, doing so also helps ensure you don't accidentally exceed Stripe's permitted rate limits.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have updated my question to accurately reflect 'Stripe'. My goal is to have an end-to-end test of my user registration process. Adding Credit Card details is part of this process, so the test can't get past this step without entering a credit card. I'm not using it to test their endpoint or API.